# iOS 14: CallKit hide call history in recents

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, call, callkit

I'm developing an application which has audio and video calling functionality and I'm using CallKit. By default it is displaying application call history in the "Recents" tab of the system Phone app. I want to hide CallKit call history from the system Phone app. Is there a way to do it? `setIncludesCallsInRecents = FALSE` only works with iOS 12, is there any way to achieve this on iOS 13 and iOS 14?

```
- (void)config {
    CXProviderConfiguration *config = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc]
                                       initWithLocalizedName:[NSBundle.mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"]];
    config.ringtoneSound = @"notes_of_the_optimistic.caf";
   
    NSLog(@"config provider delegate");
    //Bhoomi
    config.supportsVideo = FALSE;
    
    //config.supportsVideo = TRUE;

    [config setIncludesCallsInRecents:FALSE];

    config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"callkit_logo"]);
    
    
    NSArray *ar = @[ [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)CXHandleTypeGeneric] ];

    NSSet *handleTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:ar];
    [config setSupportedHandleTypes:handleTypes];
   
    [config setMaximumCallGroups:2];
    [config setMaximumCallsPerCallGroup:1];
    
    //[config setMaximumCallGroups:3];
    //[config setMaximumCallsPerCallGroup:2];
    
    self.provider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:config];
    [self.provider setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.observer setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 
}
```

Comment: The problem should be somewhere else. In my app I set `includesCallsInRecents` to `false` and it works on iOS 13 and 14. Are you sure that the other configurations work? For example, do you see the `callkit_logo` that you've set as the `iconTemplateImageData`?

Comment: @Marco The problem was somewhere else. This helped a lot